# Logs 100K request per second in real-time with python logging package

Tags: python, logging, syslog

I have to get the data from one of my localhost ports and saved it to a log file. To do this, I use the `logging` package. Here is my code:

1. In the first step I designed my custom `TimedRotatingFileHandler`:

   ```
   from logging.handlers import BaseRotatingHandler, 
   TimedRotatingFileHandler
   from itertools import islice
   import logging
   import time
   import os

   _intervals = {
    "S": 1,
    "M": 60,
    "H": 60 * 60,
    "D": 60 * 60 * 24,
    "MIDNIGHT": 60 * 60 * 24,
    "W": 60 * 60 * 24 * 7}


   class CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler(BaseRotatingHandler):
       """File handler that uses the current time in the log filename.

       The time is quantisized to a configured interval. See
       TimedRotatingFileHandler for the meaning of the when, interval, utc and
       atTime arguments.

       If backupCount is non-zero, then older filenames that match the base
       filename are deleted to only leave the backupCount most recent copies,
       whenever opening a new log file with a different name.

       """

       def __init__(self, filenamePattern, when="h", interval=1, backupCount=0,
                    encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False, atTime=None):
           self.when = when.upper()
           self.backupCount = backupCount
           self.utc = utc
            self.atTime = atTime
           try:
                key = "W" if self.when.startswith("W") else self.when
                self.interval = _intervals[key]
           except KeyError:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Invalid rollover interval specified: {self.when}"
                ) from None
           if self.when.startswith("W"):
                if len(self.when) != 2:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "You must specify a day for weekly rollover from 0 to 6 "
                        f"(0 is Monday): {self.when}"
                    )
                if not "0" <= self.when[1] <= "6":
                    raise ValueError(
                        f"Invalid day specified for weekly rollover: {self.when}"
                    )
                self.dayOfWeek = int(self.when[1])

            self.interval = self.interval * interval
            self.pattern = os.path.abspath(os.fspath(filenamePattern))

            # determine best time to base our rollover times on
            # prefer the creation time of the most recently created log file.
            t = now = time.time()
            entry = next(self._matching_files(), None)
            if entry is not None:
                t = entry.stat().st_ctime
                while t + self.interval < now:
                    t += self.interval

            self.rolloverAt = self.computeRollover(t)

            # delete older files on startup and not delaying
            if not delay and backupCount > 0:
                keep = backupCount
                if os.path.exists(self.baseFilename):
                    keep += 1
                    delete = islice(self._matching_files(), keep, None)
                    for entry in delete:
                        os.remove(entry.path)

            # Will set self.baseFilename indirectly, and then may use
            # self.baseFilename to open. So by this point self.rolloverAt and
            # self.interval must be known.
            super().__init__(filenamePattern, "a", encoding, delay)

        @property
        def baseFilename(self):
            """Generate the 'current' filename to open"""
            # use the start of *this* interval, not the next
            t = self.rolloverAt - self.interval
            if self.utc:
                time_tuple = time.gmtime(t)
            else:
                time_tuple = time.localtime(t)
                dst = time.localtime(self.rolloverAt)[-1]
                if dst != time_tuple[-1] and self.interval > 3600:
                    # DST switches between t and self.rolloverAt, adjust
                    addend = 3600 if dst else -3600
                    time_tuple = time.localtime(t + added)
            return time.strftime(self.pattern, time_tuple)

        @baseFilename.setter
        def baseFilename(self, _):
            # assigned to by FileHandler, just ignore this as we use self.pattern
            # instead
            pass

        def _matching_files(self):
            """Generate DirEntry entries that match the filename pattern.

            The files are ordered by their last modification time, most recent
            files first.
            """
            matches = []
            pattern = self.pattern
            for entry in os.scandir(os.path.dirname(pattern)):
                if not entry.is_file():
                    continue
                try:
                    time.strptime(entry.path, pattern)
                    matches.append(entry)
                except ValueError:
                    continue
            matches.sort(key=lambda e: e.stat().st_mtime, reverse=True)
            return iter(matches)

        def doRollover(self):
            """Do a roll-over. This basically needs to open a new generated filename.
            """
            if self.stream:
                self.stream.close()
                self.stream = None

            if self.backupCount > 0:
                delete = islice(self._matching_files(), self.backupCount, None)
                for entry in delete:
                    os.remove(entry.path)

            now = int(time.time())
            rollover = self.computeRollover(now)
            while rollover <= now:
                rollover += self.interval
            if not self.utc:
                # If DST changes and midnight or weekly rollover, adjust for this.
                if self.when == "MIDNIGHT" or self.when.startswith("W"):
                    dst = time.localtime(now)[-1]
                    if dst != time.localtime(rollover)[-1]:
                        rollover += 3600 if dst else -3600
            self.rolloverAt = rollover

            if not self.delay:
                self.stream = self._open()

        # borrow *some* TimedRotatingFileHandler methods
        computeRollover = TimedRotatingFileHandler.computeRollover
        shouldRollover = TimedRotatingFileHandler.shouldRollover


    def setup_handlers():
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        loggers = {'log_t': logging.getLogger('t'),
                   'log_b': logging.getLogger('b'),
                   'log': logging.getLogger('log')}

        for logger in loggers:
            loggers[logger].setLevel(logging.INFO)
            if logger == 'log':
                when = 'M'
                interval = 5
                backup_count = 24
                filename_pattern = 'logs/%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M.txt'

            else:
                when = 'H'
                interval = 1
                backup_count = 2
                filename_pattern = f'logs/%Y_%m_%d_%H_{logger}.txt'

            handler = CustomTimedRotatingFileHandler(filenamePattern=filename_pattern,
                                                     when=when, interval=interval, backupCount=backup_count)
            handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            loggers[logger].addHandler(handler)

        return loggers
   ```
2. In the second step, I created a `Syslog` class to get the data from the port:

   ```
   from handler import setup_handlers
   import socketserver
   import os
   import re

   HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 8080

   PATTERNS = [r'pattern1', r'pattern2', r'pattern3', r'pattern4',
               r'pattern5', r'pattern6', r'pattern7', r'pattern8']


   class SysLogUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

       @staticmethod
       def __check_log_type(text):

           if 'LOG_T' in text:
               log_type = 'teardown'
           elif 'LOG_B' in text:
               log_type = 'built'
           else:
               log_type = None

           return log_type

       @staticmethod
       def __get_pattern(pattern, text):

           result = re.split(pattern, text)
           if len(result) > 1:
               result = result[1].split(',')[0]

           else:
               result = ' '

           return result

       def __get_data(self, data) -> str:

           logs = ''
           for pattern in PATTERNS:
               log = self.__get_pattern(pattern=pattern, text=data)
               if log:
                   logs += log
                   logs += ','

           return logs

       def handle(self) -> None:
           request = self.request[0].decode()
           log_type = self.__check_log_type(request)
           if log_type in ['log_t', 'log_b']:
               logs = self.__get_data(data=request)
               loggers[log_type].info(logs)

           else:
               print('Invalid log type!')

           data = bytes.decode(self.request[0])
           loggers['log'].info(data)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       try:
           os.makedirs('logs', exist_ok=True)
           loggers = setup_handlers()
           server = socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), SysLogUDPHandler)
           server.serve_forever(poll_interval=0.5)
       except (IOError, SystemExit):
           raise
       except KeyboardInterrupt:
           print("Ctrl+C Pressed. Shutting down.")
   ```

The challenge is the rate of requests per second is around 100,000 which is really high. Therefore, I miss a huge part of the requests. I guess it is around 80%! What is the best practice to log this amount of data?

Comment: I would think 100k requests per second would be too fast. Have you benchmarked your connection? I.e. whats the max throughput ? https://serverfault.com/questions/918699/how-do-i-obtain-requests-per-second-and-latency-per-request-for-a-udp-request

Comment: I wrote a simple python code to get the numbers. At first moment, I think something else is wrong. However, I figure out that the request rate is too fast. @JasonChia

Comment: 100k rps looks like a lot for simple python code. Maybe try switch to ThreadingUDPServer  or even better to some couroutine based network library. And also profile and optimize your message handling code to work faster. Maybe store messages in a queue in memory first and when write to disk.

Comment: That simple python code measured the rps. You are right. This the first time I encounter this amount of rps and do not have any idea. @Nikolay